# Is UbuntuOne encrypted?

Tags: ubuntu-one, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu One Encryption?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16015/ubuntu-one-encryption)

A simple question: is the connection between client and server encrypted and are the stored data on the server encrypted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the connections related to Ubuntu One are encrypted. The data is stored unencrypted, however.